# Core Data Transformable Attribute

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to access properties of a transformable core data object like this:

```
MainObject *localObject = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
TransformableObject *actualObject = localObject.transformableObject;
```

This works fine. I `NSLog` `actualObject` and get the correct key/value pairs:

```
actualObject:{

    property = "Foo";
    property2 = "Apple";
}
```

However, when I I try to:

`NSLog (@"property:%@",actualObject.property)` I get `-[__NSCFDictionary property]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

What am I doing wrong? In my Core Data Class, I have:

```
@interface MainObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) TransformableObjectClass *transformableObject;
```

EDIT:
Here's how I set the object in Core Data

```
        MainObject *event = (MainObject *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MainObject" inManagedObjectContext:[AppDelegateMy managedObjectContext]];
        [event setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:[myArrray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: How are you setting the value of `localObject.transformableObject` initially? How is the attribute configured in your model? `actualObject` is clearly an `NSDictionary`, but you haven't given us enough information to deduce why.

Comment: TransformableObjectClass is another Core Data NSManagedObject Class.

Comment: That's as may be, but the error shows that what's actually assigned to that property is an instance of `NSDictionary`. So, how'd it get there?

Comment: just added an edit, which I do through a for loop for each object in my JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` nor Core Data is magical enough to make this work without some more effort on your part. Right now, you're just assigning the dictionary in your JSON response to the new managed object's `transformableObject` property. If you tried to save your context, my guess is that it would probably fail. If you want those dictionaries turned into actual `TransformableObjectClass` instances, you need to do that yourself.

If you have a lot of this sort of thing in your app, you might want to look into [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit), or one of the other Open Source JSON-to-object mapping libraries like [ClassMapper](https://github.com/pashields/ClassMapper).

Comment: It saves fine, and why can I access actualObject above as a property of the NSManagedObject if -setValuesForKeysWithDictionary isn't working?

Comment: It's working fine. It just isn't doing what you think. In Objective-C, pointer types are more descriptive than proscriptive. If you put a dictionary into that property instead of the class you declared it as, the runtime won't complain. But if you try to send that dictionary a message it doesn't support, it'll crash. Like you're seeing.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the model configuration? Specifically the properties of the attribute in question?